# unable to run android project

Tags: android

i am unable to run android project. everytime i got error like this when i run app.

[2011-03-04 22:30:44 - Emulator] NAND: could not create temp file for system NAND disk image: No such file or directory

plz tell me what should i do..........

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just close that emulator once & try to clean the workspace like eclipse=>project=>clean now it will build it just check you are able to run project.

Answer (score 0):

that message means your current user doesn't have write and execute permissions on the 'android' folder in your temp folder (e.g. /tmp/android). use "chomod u+wx /tmp/android" to add access permission

Answer (score 0):

Your  temp File may be missing.

Goto  C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\

create  temp folder under  local  and start the emulator.